# How to use "require" when I use "window.onload"?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to make LINE LIFF work with google sheet.
I want to require "google-spreadsheet" to let the LIFF  can upload the data to the googlesheet.
But it couldn't run successfully.

By the way,I made it by modifying the codes at https://github.com/line/line-liff-v2-starter.
And the codes below which I used was from Public/liff-starter.js

*I am new to nodejs. All help and solutions are appreciated, thanks.

I'm trying to put the testing.js into liff-starter.js.

testing.js . It can work.

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const creds = require('./client_secret.json');

async function accessSpreadsheet(){
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1jW6jvUXP8aSYcSMh7RDLp1_OXo0Rg4g9fMkFmS90hkM');
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
    const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
    const rows = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
        offset:1
    });
    rows.forEach(row =>{
        if(row.userid=='dog'){
            var num = parseInt(row.point,10);
            num+=1;
            row.point = num;
            row.save();
        }
    })
}

accessSpreadsheet();
```

liff-starter.js(just the promblem part).I wrote like these recently.

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const creds = require('./client_secret.json')

//=========same as the Api,there were no problem without my modify.=====
window.onload = ......
//======================================================================
function registerButtonHandlers() {
    // scanCode call
    document.getElementById('scanQrCodeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!liff.isInClient()) {
            sendAlertIfNotInClient();
        } else {
            liff.scanCode().then(result => {
                // e.g. result = { value: "Hello LIFF app!" }
                const stringifiedResult = JSON.stringify(result);
                document.getElementById('scanQrField').textContent = stringifiedResult;
                if(result.value == "123456"){
                    accessSpreadsheet();  //here's the promblem module
                }
                toggleQrCodeReader();
            }).catch(err => {
                document.getElementById('scanQrField').textContent = "scanCode failed!";
            });
        }
    });


}

//here is the problem module content
async function accessSpreadsheet(){
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('GOOGLE_SHEET_ID');
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
    const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
    const rows = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
        offset:1
    });
    rows.forEach(row =>{
        if(row.userid=='dog'){
            var num = parseInt(row.point,10);
            num+=1;
            row.point = num;
            row.save();
        }
    })
}
```

The whole codes of liff-starter.js

```
cconst GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const creds = require('./client_secret.json')

window.onload = function() {
    const useNodeJS = true;   // if you are not using a node server, set this value to false
    const defaultLiffId = "";   // change the default LIFF value if you are not using a node server
    console.log('here');
    // DO NOT CHANGE THIS
    let myLiffId = "";
    var usetID;
    // if node is used, fetch the environment variable and pass it to the LIFF method
    // otherwise, pass defaultLiffId
    if (useNodeJS) {
        fetch('/send-id')
            .then(function(reqResponse) {
                return reqResponse.json();
            })
            .then(function(jsonResponse) {
                myLiffId = jsonResponse.id;
                initializeLiffOrDie(myLiffId);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                document.getElementById("liffAppContent").classList.add('hidden');
                document.getElementById("nodeLiffIdErrorMessage").classList.remove('hidden');
            });
    } else {
        myLiffId = defaultLiffId;
        initializeLiffOrDie(myLiffId);
    }
};

/**
* Check if myLiffId is null. If null do not initiate liff.
* @param {string} myLiffId The LIFF ID of the selected element
*/
function initializeLiffOrDie(myLiffId) {
    if (!myLiffId) {
        document.getElementById("liffAppContent").classList.add('hidden');
        document.getElementById("liffIdErrorMessage").classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
        initializeLiff(myLiffId);
    }
}

/**
* Initialize LIFF
* @param {string} myLiffId The LIFF ID of the selected element
*/
function initializeLiff(myLiffId) {
    liff
        .init({
            liffId: myLiffId
        })
        .then(() => {
            // start to use LIFF's api
            initializeApp();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            document.getElementById("liffAppContent").classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById("liffInitErrorMessage").classList.remove('hidden');
        });
}

/**
 * Initialize the app by calling functions handling individual app components
 */
function initializeApp() {
    liff.getProfile()
    .then(profile => {
        usetID = profile.userId
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error', err);
    });

    registerButtonHandlers();

}

/**
* Display data generated by invoking LIFF methods
*/

/**
* Toggle the login/logout buttons based on the isInClient status, and display a message accordingly
*/


/**
* Register event handlers for the buttons displayed in the app
*/



function registerButtonHandlers() {
    // scanCode call
    document.getElementById('scanQrCodeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!liff.isInClient()) {
            sendAlertIfNotInClient();
        } else {
            liff.scanCode().then(result => {
                // e.g. result = { value: "Hello LIFF app!" }
                const stringifiedResult = JSON.stringify(result);
                document.getElementById('scanQrField').textContent = stringifiedResult;
                if(result.value == "123456"){
                    accessSpreadsheet();  //here's the promblem module
                }
                toggleQrCodeReader();
            }).catch(err => {
                document.getElementById('scanQrField').textContent = "scanCode failed!";
            });
        }
    });


}

/**
* Alert the user if LIFF is opened in an external browser and unavailable buttons are tapped
*/
function sendAlertIfNotInClient() {
    alert('This button is unavailable as LIFF is currently being opened in an external browser.');
}

/**
* Toggle access token data field
*/
function toggleAccessToken() {
    toggleElement('accessTokenData');
}

/**
* Toggle profile info field
*/
function toggleProfileData() {
    toggleElement('profileInfo');
}

/**
* Toggle scanCode result field
*/
function toggleQrCodeReader() {
    toggleElement('scanQr');
}

/**
* Toggle specified element
* @param {string} elementId The ID of the selected element
*/
function toggleElement(elementId) {
    const elem = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (elem.offsetWidth > 0 && elem.offsetHeight > 0) {
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        elem.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

async function accessSpreadsheet(){
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1jW6jvUXP8aSYcSMh7RDLp1_OXo0Rg4g9fMkFmS90hkM');
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
    const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
    const rows = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
        offset:1
    });
    rows.forEach(row =>{
        if(row.userid=='dog'){
            var num = parseInt(row.point,10);
            num+=1;
            row.point = num;
            row.save();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: No.It didn't show any errors when I run the index.js .It showed `app listening on port 5000!`By the way , sorry that I changed my question just now , cause the old one was not really clear.Moreover thank to reply me.